# How do I set the additivity in Spring Boot logback via Spring properites?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback, spring-logback

I'm aware of the additivity attribute in logback.xml, but how do I specify that in application.properties?
I have something like this:

```
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p [%t] %logger#%M:%L %m%n
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.com.mypackage=INFO
logging.level.com.mypackage.a=DEBUG
logging.level.com.mypackage.a.b=INFO
```

Is there something like the following?:

```
logging.additivity.com.mypackage=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a logback.xml to configure additional features.

Like described here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html